# Service, thread or asyncatask for connecting to server and receiving messages

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, service, android-asynctask

I want to connect to a server using Socket and I don't quite understand one thing:
what class(thread, service, asynctask) should I use when connecting to server and then when receiving any messages from it.

AFAIK, asynctasks are good for short term operations like requesting some info from DB, threads and services are good when it comes to long-term one like downloading something.

So here's where I stuck: connecting to server is a short-term operation. However, receiving all the messages from server is not one because this operation has to be performed until app will be closed. Thus, there are one short-term and one long-term operations and one class to handle both of them. Which class should it be? If I've messed up something with all these classes please tell me.

Comment: Is the server sending messages just when it likes to or just one message after a client sent a command?

Comment: @greenapps More like  whenever it likes. It's messenger type application.

Comment: You want a permanent connection? Then use a thread in a service.

Comment: @greenapps I'm not sure what do you mean. I want it in such a way that after it's set connection would disappear only when the app itself is closed

Comment: That is called closing a connection.